# XML and Multimodule Project

Tags: android, android-layout, multi-module

I am just recently approaching this architecture and was implementing screens in my feature module. The screen in question should have a toolbar, in this case a material toolbar and a material Chip.

Right from the start I noticed problems with the rendering of the components in question, i.e., they are not shown in the Android Studio preview

What follows is the very simple screen design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <!-- Variables here -->
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_arrow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/chip_status"
            layout="@layout/chip_status_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is the rendering of Android studio:

[image: error in rendering]

You can see right away that that doesn't appear to be a Chip and especially the toolbar is not rendered.

Below is the error I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please set start drawable using R.attr#chipIcon.
    at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.validateAttributes(Chip.java:393)
    at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:206)
    at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:198)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1074.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:164)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1165)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:884)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:293)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```